# Netsuite API post salesorder

Tags: api, rest, netsuite

I'm trying to post a salesorder to Netsuite REST API, and following what appears to be the correct format according to documentation.

I'm posting to /services/rest/record/v1/salesOrder

My payload looks like this

```
{"recordtype":"salesorder","entity":{"id":"20716"},"total":119.21,"createdDate":"2023-01-25T16:04:59+00:00","item":{"items":[{"item":{"id":"959"},"quantity":1,"amount":111.41}]}}
```

I'm having no issues connecting and authenticating and am performing other (GET) operations without any issues.

The response to the above request is

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1
    [title] => Bad Request
    [status] => 400
    [o:errorDetails] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [detail] => Please enter a value for [entity]
                    [o:errorPath] => entity
                    [o:errorCode] => FIELD_PARAM_REQD
                )
        )
    )
```

The value I have in the 'entity' node is a valid netsuite customer record ID.

For reference, the salesOrder object schema is here - https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2022.2/index.html#/definitions/salesOrder

Any idea why Netsuite is complaining about the entity?

Comment: Just try the `id` as is (not as an object) => `... , "entity": "20716", ...` ?

Comment: same outcome...

Comment: Shouldn't the id by an integer ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the format I was posting is correct, but I was posting it in the 'form_data' node rather than the 'body' node.

So for anyone else with similar issue, the payload is correct.